# How to get delegated instance in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'd like to get the instance of a delegated class.

Specifically, in the following example, I'd like to get an instance of the passed `Base` - `b` but get an error when trying to use `b`.

```
interface Base {
    fun print()
}

class BaseImpl(val x: Int) : Base {
    override fun print() { print(x) }
}

open class Derived(b: Base) : Base by b {
    override fun print() {
        printSomethingBefore()
        b.print() // b isn't recognized :(
        printSomethingAfter()
    }
}
```

* Source for the example: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html

Answer (score 3):

Declaring `b` with the `val` prefix did the trick:

... Derived(**val** b: Base) : Base by b ...